# How do I create an boolean equals method compares objects in an array

Tags: java

My programming assignment tasked me with writing an increase/decreasePay abstract method that must be put in my abstract employee class. I can't seem to get the the method correct in HourlyWorker so that it will take increase or decrease the pay by a "percentage". My math is sound (monthly pay - or + (monthly pay * the percentage), but my output in my test class is coming out the same after increasing/decreasing pay. Any help?

Employee class:

```
abstract public class Employee
{

private String lastName;
private String firstName;
private String ID;


public abstract void increasePay(double percentage);
public abstract void decreasePay(double percentage);
public abstract double getMonthlyPay();

public Employee(String last, String first, String ID)
   {
   lastName = last;
   firstName = first;
   this.ID = ID;
   } 

public void setLast(String last)
   {
      lastName = last;
   }
   
public void setFirst(String first)
   {
      firstName = first;
   }
   
public void setIdNumber(String ID)
   {
      this.ID = ID;
   }

      
public String getLastName()
{
   return lastName;
}

public String getFirstName()
{
   return firstName;
}

public String getName()
{
   return firstName + lastName;
}

public String getIdNumber()
{
   return ID;
}
}

HourlyWorkerClass

public class HourlyWorker extends Employee
{
private int hours;
private double hourlyRate;
private double monthlyPay;

public HourlyWorker(String last, String first, String ID, double rate)
{
   super(last, first, ID);
   hourlyRate = rate;
}

public void setHours(int hours)
{
   this.hours = hours;
}

public int getHours()
{
   return hours;
}

public void setHourlyRate(double rate)
{
   if ( hours > 160 )
       this.hourlyRate = hourlyRate * 1.5;
    else 
       this.hourlyRate = rate;
}

public double getHourlyRate()
{
   return hourlyRate;
}


public void setMonthlyPay(double monthlyPay)
{
   monthlyPay = hourlyRate * hours;
}

public double getMonthlyPay()
{
   return hourlyRate * hours;
}

public void increasePay(double percentage)
{
   monthlyPay = monthlyPay* percentage;
}

public void decreasePay(double percentage)
{
   monthlyPay = monthlyPay* percentage;
}

public String toString() 
   {
        String result = "Name: " + getFirstName() + " " + getLastName() + "\nID: "
                         + getIdNumber() + " \nHourly Rate: " + hourlyRate;
                        return result;
   }

}
```

Testing class (currently testing increase

```
public class TestEmployee2
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   Employee [] staff = new Employee[3];
      Supervisor sup = new Supervisor("Boss", "Jim", "JB7865", 54000);
      HourlyWorker hw1 = new HourlyWorker("Bee", "Busy", "BB1265", 11.95);

      hw1.setHours(200);
            
      staff[0] = sup;
      staff[1] = hw1;        
      
   System.out.println(staff[0].getMonthlyPay());
   staff[0].increasePay(5);
   System.out.println(staff[0].getMonthlyPay());

   System.out.println(staff[1].getMonthlyPay());
   staff[1].increasePay(10);
   System.out.println(staff[1].getMonthlyPay());
   
}
}
Supervisor class:

public class Supervisor extends Employee
{
private double annualSalary;
private double monthlyPay;

public Supervisor(String last, String first, String ID, double salary)
{
   super(last, first, ID);
   annualSalary = salary;
}

public void setAnnualSalary(double salary)
{
   annualSalary = salary;
}

public double getAnnualSalary()
{
   return annualSalary;
}

public double getMonthlyPay()
{
   return ((annualSalary + (annualSalary * .02)) / 12);
}

public void increasePay(double percentage)
{
   monthlyPay = monthlyPay* percentage;
}

public void decreasePay(double percentage)
{
   monthlyPay = monthlyPay* percentage;
}

public String toString() 
   {
        String result = "Name: " + getFirstName() + " " + getLastName() + "\nID: "
                         + getIdNumber() + "\nAnnual Salary: " + annualSalary;
         return result;
   }
}
```

Output is:

4590.0 4590.0 2390.0 2390.0

Doesn't appear to be modifying getMonthlyPay()

Should be:

4590.00 4819.50 2390.00 2629.00

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What you are describing is not suitable for an `equals()` method, because to be equal to something else it must be of the same type to make sense, but is suitable for a Predicate to be used say in a filter operation.

Comment: @ChocolateGoosePoosey I couldn’t see the forest for the trees - you have a lot of trees in your question. So you just want an equals method that returns true if the object passed to it is “the same”. Fine. If you implement that, then `myStockList.contains(someStockItem)` will work as you would expect. What’s the problem exactly with implementing equals()? BTW I would compare `symbol` instead of `sharePrice`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, when implementing `equals()`, you compare “key” fields whose values don’t change for the entity, and don’t compare “state” fields whose values change from time to time.

You are comparing `sharePrice`, when I believe you should be comparing `symbol`.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `list.indexOf(temp)`, what that does, right now, is look for a `Stock` that is `equals` to the argument passed to it -- so it looks for a `Stock` with price zero, not caring about the symbol at all.  That's what the code does right now.

Honestly, using `indexOf` and `equals` is not really appropriate for this problem.  `indexOf` is really only useful when you have something that's *totally* equal to the target you're looking for.

The *best* way to do something like this is

```
Optional<Stock> foundStock = list.stream().filter(stock -> stock.getName().equals(symbol)).findAny();
if (foundStock.isPresent()) {
  // do something with foundStock.get()
} else {
  // no found stock
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf()` is a method return the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in the returned list. If the list does not contain this element, value -1 is returned.
More formally, return the lowest index i that meets the following conditions:

```java
if(o==null? get(i)==null :o.equals(get(i))){
    return i;
}
return -1;
```

If there is no such index, return -1.

And you have override the `equals` method, I guess you just want to focus on the same price Stock?:

```java
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj){
    if (obj instanceof Stock){   
        Stock other = (Stock) obj;
        return getPrice() == other.getPrice();
   }
   return false;
}
```

As my opinion, you have use `List<Stock> list` so the Object in the list is all `Stock`. Maybe it could be simplifed:

```java
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj){
    Stock other = (Stock) obj;
    return getPrice() == other.getPrice();
}
```